# How to make use of AWS Cognito Hosted UI for authorization code grant flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using the Amplify CLI to create a Cognito user pool for my React web application. I've found the withAuthentication UI doesn't meet my needs because I can't customize the signin form (say to remove the phone number field) or protect just part of my app.

Instead, I would like to use the Hosted UI provided by Cognito but am struggling with how to implement the Authorization Code Grant flow. Is there an easy to use the npm library to help me with this?

I've tried directly calling the /authorize endpoint as described in the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/) but get a cors error when calling from localhost. I've also tried using window.location.ref to redirect to the hosted URL that the Cognito Console provides a link to. This works but when arriving back on my specified page (following the callback), parse the code from the query string, and send a POST request to the /token endpoint as described in the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/), I get a 400 status code back. Is there more I need to be doing here?

I'm very new to OAuth so would appreciate any simple explanations or pointers to basic materials a noob can understand would be great!

Answer (score 0):

My resources use code flow with Cognito and will give you sonething to compare against:

- [Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/25/basicspa-execution/)

A couple of pointers:

- Register an OAuth client in your user pool to fix the CORS error
- Trace [OAuth messages](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/) from the browser and focus on getting them the same as mine

My code sample is easy to run against my Cognito endpoint. It does not use React or Amplify though - but once you understand principles it should be easy to port them to your own technology choices.